# Trigger execution of user-defined Excel function from VBA sub

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I want to automatically download financial data by using Excel and save that data. The download of the data is done by an Excel add-in. ISINs are used as the data identifier. The process looks as follows:

- Open Workbook
- Replace the existing ISIN with a new one
- Download data
- Export data
- Close file

The data download is done by a custom function which is defined inside the Excel Add-in (and which I cannot access as it is password protected): `INFGETHIST()`, one function parameter is an ISIN. Unfortunately, the function does not load the data until the VBA macro I am using to update the ISIN and close the workbook afterwards is fully executed - which means, the workbook gets closed before the data is updated.

I've tried the following

- `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`
- `Calculate` and

```
Sub WaitUntilFinished()
    Application.Calculate
    If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
        DoEvents
    End If
End Sub
```

but to no avail.

I'm searching for a way to trigger the download of the data before my code executes completely. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are running `INFGETHIST()`?

Comment: Hi, sorry that this remained unclear. `INFGETHIST()` is a worksheet function that is inserted into cells, like `=INFGETHIST("ISIN XY")`